# Batch Command Explanation

Tags: batch-file

I don't know what to call this, anyway, I not much with batch scripting, I just want to know what this line is trying to do, most specifically the | (pipe symbol) and /macro32, don't worry about the pcmlog32

```
echo End   Running PRJH.BAT  | pcmlog32 /macro2
```

Thank you.

Comment: The `/macro2` is an argument to `pcmlog32`, whatever that may be. It is impossible to describe the purpose of `/macro2` without understanding `pcmlog32`

Comment: @dbenham - now that makes things clearer, making this question completely answered. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the output of `echo End   Running PRJH.BAT` will be taken as input for   `pcmlog32 /macro2` .
See [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) .Though  i don't know what  `pcmlog32` is as it is not standard  windows command.

Comment: Lol, I was just about to submit the exact same answer.

Comment: It's an academic question by the look of it.

Comment: @foxidrive - indeed a very academic question, however, some of us who never came using these scripting languages that much will always wonder and will end up asking.. resources on the web is ubiquitous, that makes it difficult to understand such academic question.